# Getting the currently active keyboard language as NSLocale

Tags: ios, swift, uitextinput

I already found a lot of approaches for this but no working solution. Here's what I tried and didn't work.

(1) Simply calling **primaryLanguage()**

```
UITextInputMode().primaryLanguage
```

→ always returns nil :-/

(2) Subscribing to **UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChangeNotification** notifications

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "changeInputMode:", name: UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
}

func changeInputMode(sender : NSNotification) {
    ...?!
}
```

The notification is getting triggered but it is unclear how I can extract the current language information from the notification.

(3) Using **activeInputModes()**

```
let localeIdentifier = UITextInputMode.activeInputModes().first as? UITextInputMode
var locale:NSLocale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: localeIdentifier.primaryLanguage!)
println("Input Mode Language \(localeIdentifier.primaryLanguage!)")
```

This always provides the same array of all available keyboards, no information on the actually active one.

How do I get the NSLocale of the currently active keyboard?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can access the primaryLanguage from every textfield by accessing the textfields `textInputMode` like that:

```
var language = textfield.textInputMode?.primaryLanguage
```

Comment: Great, that works. The only downside is that it only returns a value once the textview or textfield has become active – otherwise it's nil. It would be nice to also get the active keyboard language right after viewDidLoad and even before showing it.

Comment: The keyboard doesn't exist until the text field becomes active.