# Keyboard Language in React Native iOS?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

Is there any way to know the language of the Keyboard in React-Native iOS apps?

Cause I want to switch `TextInput` direction automatically based on current language

Comment: Did you found solution?

Comment: No I unfortunately didn't...

Comment: If you still looking for same. i have suggestion that you check text whether it is english or arabic

Comment: I got your point ... and I implemented it that way ... but ideally I wanted to **Auto-Switch** keyboard <<before-typing>> ... but thank you anyway...

Answer (score 1):

You can get the devide locale using:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native'

const locale = NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLocale ||
               NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLanguages[0]
```

It should produce something like:

`"fr_FR"`

The keyboard language itself, i didn't found anything until now.

### Edit

You can get the keyboard language if you create an `native module`.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17670922/get-keyboard-language-or-detect-user-input-language-in-android/28216764) a example of how to get it using java for android:

```
private void printInputLanguages() {
   InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
   List<InputMethodInfo> ims = imm.getEnabledInputMethodList();

   for (InputMethodInfo method : ims) {
       List<InputMethodSubtype> submethods = imm.getEnabledInputMethodSubtypeList(method, true);
       for (InputMethodSubtype submethod : submethods) {
          if (submethod.getMode().equals("keyboard")) {
             String currentLocale = submethod.getLocale();
             Log.i(TAG, "Available input method locale: " + currentLocale);
          }
       }
   }
}
```

And [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28682576/getting-the-currently-active-keyboard-language-as-nslocale) how to do it with swift, for IOS:

```
var language = textfield.textInputMode?.primaryLanguage
```

And [here's](https://medium.com/wix-engineering/creating-a-native-module-in-react-native-93bab0123e46) how to create a native module for react-native

Comment: Thank you for your answer ... But what I need is the **Current Active Keyboard Lang** not the general **Device Locale**

Comment: I updated my question. Hope it helps. If it does, leave at least an upvote. Thanks!

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli have you found any solution?

Comment: @HeratPatel unforunately, no