# detect keyboard language(or direction of it) in react native

Tags: android, react-native

I need to detect the **keyboard language** not the locale or device language or anything else. and i can't write java code. is there any way to find the language of the keyboard ?

in this case it should show 'en' or 'ltr'

[image: in this case it must show en or ltr]

in this case it should show 'fa' or 'rtl'

[image: and in this case it must say fa or rtl]

i am using i18n but i don't need the locale, its fixed and i can't get the info i need from it.

react-native : 0.59.5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keyboard Language in React Native iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64009740/keyboard-language-in-react-native-ios)

Comment: @XplosiVe06 This question is about Android.

Comment: @XplosiVe06 no it doesn't help

Comment: I don't believe this issue should be closed. The linked question is not relevant. Looking for reopen votes.

Comment: @Slbox I agree, opening now

Answer (score 1):

You can get the keyboard language if you create an `native module`.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17670922/get-keyboard-language-or-detect-user-input-language-in-android/28216764) a example of how to get it using java for android:

```java
private void printInputLanguages() {
   InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
   List<InputMethodInfo> ims = imm.getEnabledInputMethodList();

   for (InputMethodInfo method : ims) {
       List<InputMethodSubtype> submethods = imm.getEnabledInputMethodSubtypeList(method, true);
       for (InputMethodSubtype submethod : submethods) {
          if (submethod.getMode().equals("keyboard")) {
             String currentLocale = submethod.getLocale();
             Log.i(TAG, "Available input method locale: " + currentLocale);
          }
       }
   }
}
```

And [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28682576/getting-the-currently-active-keyboard-language-as-nslocale) how to do it with swift, for IOS:

```js
var language = textfield.textInputMode?.primaryLanguage
```

And [here's](https://medium.com/wix-engineering/creating-a-native-module-in-react-native-93bab0123e46) how to create a native module for react-native

[EDIT]

You might get what you need using the `NativeModules` module from react-native itself, like as follows:

```js
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native'

[...]

//Getting the device language:
// iOS
let deviceLanguage = NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLocale || NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLanguages[0]

// Android
let deviceLanguage = NativeModules.I18nManager.localeIdentifier

//Getting keyboard Information (1)
// iOS:
let keyboardData = NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings

// Android:
let keyboardData = NativeModules.I18nManager
```

(1): I did not test this, you will need to see the output and see if it helps in your case. But, the output for IOS should look like this:

```
{
    [...]

    AppleKeyboards: [
        "es_419@sw=QWERTY-Spanish;hw=Automatic",
        "en_US@sw=QWERTY;hw=Automatic",
        "fr_FR@hw=US;sw=QWERTY",
        "emoji@sw=Emoji"
    ]
    AppleLanguages: ["fr-US", "en-US", "es-US", "en"],
    NSLanguages: ["fr-US", "en-US", "es-US", "en"],
    AppleLanguagesDidMigrate: "9.2",
    AppleLocale: "fr_FR"
    
   [...]
}
```

Got this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33468746/whats-the-best-way-to-get-device-locale-in-react-native-ios).

Comment: Seems like `textfield.textInputMode?.primaryLanguage` returns null :(

Comment: @Exoriri according to some comments on the answer I linked in my answer:

"The only downside is that it only returns a value once the textview or textfield has become active – otherwise it's nil."

Comment: @Exoriri added some more info on my answer. Hope it helps. If not, You will need to create your own `native module` for it. Upvote my answer if it helps!